# C/C++ vs Objective-C Arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, arrays

So, I'm making an iPhone app in Objective-C and need to use an array. Usually in Objective-C I'd use NSArray or NSMutableArray, but I'm starting to wonder if that's the best idea when simply using a basic array. Memory- and efficiency-wise, does it make more sense to use a regular C array or an Objective-C array when simply keeping a basica array of custom objects?  And do you usually use C arrays or Objective-C arrays when programming in Objective-C? Thanks!

Comment: +1 I think about this when I want an array of ints, for example. Converting to and from NSNumber is a pain and probably inefficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This really just depends on what you want to do with the array.

For arrays of numbers that you're going to do lots of math on, C arrays are probably a better choice (or at least a class that wraps C arrays). If you're constantly converting back and forth between scalars and objects and aren't using any of NSArray's more advanced features, all it will buy you is a lot of overhead.

However, Cocoa objects have a number of memory management invariants that you must obey or your app will go boom. C arrays and C++ vectors will blissfully ignore these requirements, meaning a lot more work for you to keep them in line. NSArray will take care of these for you. When you're dealing with Cocoa objects, use an NSArray.

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question. I guess I'll just use the Cocoa classes in this situation. However, I see where you're coming from when performing math on arrays, and I'll keep that in mind when doing something like that.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I've found a good reason to *not* use them, `NSArray` is my de-facto choice.

And in several years of Cocoa programming, I've never really found a good reason to not use it.  The only things I've been able to come up with are when then things I want to store in an array are not objects, or I want to store objects but not have them be retained.  In both of those cases, however, a simple `CFMutableArrayRef` with custom value callbacks does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

When in rome.

Use NSArray or NSMutableArray when developing iPhone applications, as that is the idiomatic thing to do.

Unless you have a very specific reason to use plain old c arrays, stick to the idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 0):

NSArray and NSMutableArray are quite efficient. If performance isn't a problem for you yet, there's no reason to contort yourself into using plain C arrays when Objective-C objects would be more natural – if performance becomes a problem later, then you can optimize it more.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C arrays (NSArray, et.al.) are grossly inefficient if you are trying to use them for processing samples of real-time multi-channel audio and/or raw pixels of real-time video, bits that you need to touch on the order of many millions of times per second.  Plain C arrays of data laid out in some data cache line aware manner are much more appropriate, and likely to use far less memory and battery power for any significant processing.

Note that you can't even feed NSArrays to the Accelerate framework, and most of the Core Audio, Core Graphics or Open GL APIs.

For data you seldom touch, say at a rate of only many thousands of time per second or less, Objective C arrays will help with memory management and data abstraction, probably without their time and memory penalty being easily measurable.  Useful for user data, UI elements, UI tables, and other really slow stuff that happens at merely human tempos.

Comment: I beg to differ. I architected and developed several high profile video-conferencing tools, and built my real time video and audio streaming chain of processing around ObjC collections. The main benefit was removing the need to copy data from buffer to buffer for thread-safety, and instead heavily use the object-ownership model of ObjC (retain counts). I found NSArray, NSDictionary, NSSet and NSData (to say nothing of their CF 'basement' classes highly optimized, and when used along the design lines of Cocoa - vastly superior to previous implementations used.

Comment: At video frame rates, you may be OK.  But at WWDC a few years back, Apple explicitly recommended against using Objective C or Swift properties or thread-safety locks inside the audio real-time context.  I haven't seen any official retraction of that recommendation (yet?).  I use lock-free ring buffers for passing streaming data between threads (real-time software defined radio app).

Comment: What they meant then, is not to be as dumb as to allocate an Obj-C object (or CF object for that matter) per Audio "frame" (several audio samples). There are millions of them going around.... but if you work with NSArray's of NSData objects holding the audio-data in bulks (how you usually receive them from the lower-level parts of the system) then you're good to go. I would never create Obj-C objects in a tight loop - who knows how ARC or other memory-management performs under stress, and when? But as Collections - especially collections of higher-level semantic - I found them just great.

Comment: Ring buffers are fine - but you pay high price copying data into them, and out of them - all the time. What if, instead, when you receive new data, you just wrap it with NSData object, and add it to a collection, (Say an NSArray) that replaces the ring-buffer altogether? no data copying at all! this proved to be very performant. The classic Audio/Video engines copy data all the time from layer to layer - and that can be avoided with Cocoa collection classes.

Comment: Wrapping NSData or modifying collections requires memory management. Apple explicitly recommended against any Obj C code that potentially does memory management inside the audio real-time context (see WWDC 2017 session 501). –

Comment: Memory management of Obj-C is merely retain-release, when you act wisely, and as you can create NSData objects around existing memory-buffers (even those 'malloc'ed or received from a driver - you can avoid the real "memory-management. Also I indicated that large enough data chunks (like normal buffers of compressed audio most systems pass) work great for even the realtime chain. Only important thing - not to allocate/deallocate obj-C objects within realtime tight-loops. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm in basic agreement with the preferred answer, I think it lacks the underlying criteria, which is this: When programming for iPhone, the code that you write represents merely few percent (in CPU cycles Memory, etc) of the total that is done by your app. The rest - is done by Cocoa-Touch frameworks and the OS. Usually your data structures (including arrays) will only serve intermediate needs, on your way to Cocoa API calls. These, however, only accept NSArrays, NSDictionaries etc. So if you choose to use C arrays, prepare for reconstructing NSArrays from them very soon (e.g. to display data in the UI, to query a database, or to send a network request) and this bridging back-and-forth costs a lot.

In addition, Foundation collection classes (such as NSArray) are highly optimized, and adapt to different scenarios automatically (NSArray for instance can use C arrays in its implementation, and switch them to Tree structures if the Array is big, or even as a linked-list if only few indexes are populated. You will find them vastly superior to C-arrays in the long run, as you don't need to re-architect your app every time your needs change. Apple is doing this for you.

For simplistic needs and relatively small arrays - the difference in performance (if any) is negligible.

This isn't saying C arrays have no place in iPhone development - only that their (justifiable) use is rare.